# ignoring files that begins with a dot for git

Tags: git

I want to ignore the following files for commit, that is all files beginning with a dot. Here is the content of .gitignore

```
content of .gitignore
---------------------
.project
.settings/
.*
**/.*
!/.gitignore
```

so, I commited .gitignore

but when I do a `git status --ignored`, the output is

```
.DS_Store
audit-service/target/
confsvr/target/
db-service/target/
eurekasvr/target/
gate-service/target/
optimisation-fiscale-service/target/
produit-immobilier-service/target/
specialroutes-service/target/
user-service/target/
```

When I run `git check-ignore *` I have no input.

Furthermore whan I run `git add .`, it added all the files, including the files beginning with a dot.

### EDIT

Here is the output of "git status --ignored" command

```
$ git status --ignored
On branch userservice
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   .project
    new file:   .settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
    new file:   .settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
    new file:   audit-service/.classpath
    new file:   audit-service/.gitignore
    new file:   audit-service/.project
    new file:   audit-service/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
    new file:   audit-service/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
    new file:   audit-service/.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
    modified:   audit-service/pom.xml
    modified:   audit-service/src/main/docker/Dockerfile
    modified:   audit-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/audits/calculs/LoiPinelCalcul.java
    modified:   audit-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/audits/dtos/ProduitImmobilierDTO.java
    modified:   audit-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/audits/dtos/Search.java
    modified:   audit-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/audits/test.java
    modified:   audit-service/src/main/resources/application.yml
    new file:   confsvr/.classpath
    new file:   confsvr/.gitignore
    new file:   confsvr/.project
    new file:   confsvr/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
    new file:   confsvr/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
    new file:   confsvr/.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
    modified:   confsvr/src/main/docker/Dockerfile
    modified:   confsvr/src/main/resources/application.yml
    new file:   db-service/.classpath
    new file:   db-service/.gitignore
    new file:   db-service/.project
    new file:   db-service/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
    new file:   db-service/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
    new file:   db-service/.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
    modified:   db-service/pom.xml
    modified:   db-service/src/main/docker/Dockerfile
    modified:   db-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/db/Application.java
    new file:   db-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/db/controllers/UserController.java
    modified:   db-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/db/dtos/ProduitImmobilierDTO.java
    new file:   db-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/db/dtos/UserDTO.java
    new file:   db-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/db/exception/EmailExistsException.java
    modified:   db-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/db/models/ProduitImmobilier.java
    new file:   db-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/db/models/User.java
    new file:   db-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/db/repository/UserRepository.java
    modified:   db-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/db/services/ProduitImmobilierService.java
    new file:   db-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/db/services/UserService.java
    new file:   db-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/db/services/UserServiceImpl.java
    modified:   db-service/src/main/resources/application.yml
    modified:   db-service/src/main/resources/schema.sql
    modified:   docker/common/docker-compose.yml
    new file:   eurekasvr/.classpath
    new file:   eurekasvr/.gitignore
    new file:   eurekasvr/.project
    new file:   eurekasvr/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
    new file:   eurekasvr/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
    new file:   eurekasvr/.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
    modified:   eurekasvr/src/main/docker/Dockerfile
    modified:   eurekasvr/src/main/resources/application.yml
    new file:   gate-service/.classpath
    new file:   gate-service/.gitignore
    new file:   gate-service/.project
    new file:   gate-service/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
    new file:   gate-service/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
    new file:   gate-service/.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
    modified:   gate-service/src/main/docker/Dockerfile
    modified:   gate-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/gates/ZuulServerApplication.java
    modified:   gate-service/src/main/resources/application.yml
    new file:   optimisation-fiscale-service/.classpath
    new file:   optimisation-fiscale-service/.gitignore
    new file:   optimisation-fiscale-service/.project
    new file:   optimisation-fiscale-service/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
    new file:   optimisation-fiscale-service/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
    new file:   optimisation-fiscale-service/.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
    modified:   optimisation-fiscale-service/pom.xml
    modified:   optimisation-fiscale-service/src/main/docker/Dockerfile
    modified:   optimisation-fiscale-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/tax/dtos/ProduitImmobilierDTO.java
    modified:   optimisation-fiscale-service/src/main/resources/application.yml
    modified:   pom.xml
    new file:   produit-immobilier-service/.classpath
    new file:   produit-immobilier-service/.gitignore
    new file:   produit-immobilier-service/.project
    new file:   produit-immobilier-service/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
    new file:   produit-immobilier-service/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
    new file:   produit-immobilier-service/.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
    modified:   produit-immobilier-service/pom.xml
    modified:   produit-immobilier-service/src/main/docker/Dockerfile
    modified:   produit-immobilier-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/produit/dtos/ProduitImmobilierDTO.java
    modified:   produit-immobilier-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/produit/dtos/Search.java
    modified:   produit-immobilier-service/src/main/resources/application.yml
    new file:   specialroutes-service/.classpath
    new file:   specialroutes-service/.gitignore
    new file:   specialroutes-service/.project
    new file:   specialroutes-service/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
    new file:   specialroutes-service/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
    new file:   specialroutes-service/.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
    modified:   specialroutes-service/src/main/docker/Dockerfile
    modified:   specialroutes-service/src/main/resources/application.yml
    new file:   target/docker/Dockerfile
    new file:   target/test-classes/image_info.json
    new file:   user-service/.classpath
    new file:   user-service/.gitignore
    new file:   user-service/.project
    new file:   user-service/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
    new file:   user-service/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
    new file:   user-service/.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
    new file:   user-service/pom.xml
    new file:   user-service/src/main/docker/Dockerfile
    new file:   user-service/src/main/docker/run.sh
    new file:   user-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/user/Application.java
    new file:   user-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/user/controllers/UserController.java
    new file:   user-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/user/dtos/ProduitImmobilierDTO.java
    new file:   user-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/user/dtos/SecurityDTO.java
    new file:   user-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/user/dtos/UserDTO.java
    new file:   user-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/user/enumeration/PERMISSION.java
    new file:   user-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/user/exception/EmailExistsException.java
    new file:   user-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/user/exception/InternalRequestException.java
    new file:   user-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/user/services/DbService.java
    new file:   user-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/user/services/UserService.java
    new file:   user-service/src/main/java/com/immoapp/user/services/UserServiceImpl.java
    new file:   user-service/src/main/resources/application.yml
    new file:   user-service/src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml

Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .DS_Store
    audit-service/target/
    confsvr/target/
    db-service/target/
    eurekasvr/target/
    gate-service/target/
    optimisation-fiscale-service/target/
    produit-immobilier-service/target/
    specialroutes-service/target/
    user-service/target/
```

Comment: Do you have any other `.gitignore` files in your repository? It sounds like something with `!` is conflicting and re-enabling some files.

Comment: Hello Nick, yes I realized that I have other .gitignore in my repository (see EDIT). Could you tell me what I have to do to deactivate them all except the global one.

Comment: Sorry, Could you tell me what I have to do to take them all into account including the global one.

Answer (score 0):

in fact I had to simply removes the ".*" files from both the global .gitignore and in each subprojects .gitignore files

So in the global .gitignore, I wrote

```
.*
```

and in each subproject .gitignore, I wrote

```
/target/
.*
```

it seems that subproject .gitignore files overrides global .gitignore file

Comment: That makes sense. Repo > User > Global